# A theorem in Takesaki's book (Vol 2, Chapter VIII)

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

[image]

The above screenshot is from Takesaki's book.

I have two questions.

1. In the proof of Theorem 3.2. The author mention that if $\psi$ is not faithful, then we can choose $\psi^{'}$ om $M$ such that $s(\psi^{'}= 1-s(\psi)$. How to prove the existence of the weight $\psi^{'}$?
2. The proof of the last statement of the theorem is not given. I wonder how to construct $\xi\in H_{\varphi} $ such that the $\omega(x)=(\pi_{\varphi}(x)\xi,\xi)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You define $\psi'(x)=\varphi((1-s(\psi))x(1-s(\psi)))$.
2. Taking $\psi=\omega$, you have
   $$
   \omega(x)=\langle \pi_\omega(x)\,\Omega,\Omega\rangle,\ \text{ for some } \Omega\in\mathfrak H_\omega.
   $$
   Let $\xi=u\Omega$. Then
   $$
   \omega(x)=\langle u^*\pi_\omega(x)u\Omega,\Omega\rangle
   =\langle \pi_\varphi(x)u\Omega,u\Omega\rangle
   =\langle \pi_\varphi(x)\xi,\xi\rangle,
   $$
   where $\xi=u\Omega$.

Comment: If we define $\psi'(x)=\varphi((1-s(\psi))x)$, then $\varphi((1-s(\psi))x)=\psi'(s(\psi')x)$, but how to conclude $s(\psi')=1-s(\psi)$?

Comment: Changed the definition slightly to make it positive. If $\psi'=p\varphi p$ and $\psi'(q)=0$, since $\varphi$ is faithful you get $pqp=0$. So $\psi'$ is faithful on $pMp$ and $p\psi'=p\psi'p=\psi'$. That's how Takesaki defines the support.

Comment: Thanks! I have another question:  You mention that $\omega(x)=\langle \pi_\omega(x)\,\Omega,\Omega\rangle,\ \text{ for some } \Omega\in\mathfrak H_\omega.$. This conclusion can be obtined by GNS construction. But in Blackdar's book, it says that there is no natrual cyclic vector $\Omega$. Is $\Omega=1+N_{\omega}$, where $N_{\omega}=\{x\in M: \omega(x^*x)=0\}$?

Comment: Yes, that's what you do in GNS. Not sure what Blackadar means.